# Auto complete giving syntax error using with angular element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input text box where i would like to implement the auto suggest with the words retrieved through http request

```
<input type="text"   id="ingredients" ng-model="searchString" ng-change="callSuggestion()" ng-enter="getRecipesTracknPlan()" placeholder="Type of ingredients / recipe">
```

the autocomplete i am trying is 
`angular.element.('#ingredients').autocomplete({
      source: $scope.suggestionPhrase
    });`

I am gettting an error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token (

how can i rectify this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a full stop/period after `element`, which is a function.

Comment: ya i correct it now it shows "angular.element(...).autocomplete is not a function"

Comment: Where is this particular piece of code? Inside a controller? Is `autocomplete` a directive you have made? A dependency you have injected? If you create a plunkr it may help to diagnose the issue. `autocomplete` is not a standard Angular function.

Comment: no i am not writing auto complete as a directive here  yes this piece is with in a controller

Comment: So where is autocomplete coming from!?

Comment: http request  from solr